# DatePicker returns null (Android)

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to show DatePicker when user clicks the calendar icon in `ActionBar` and set the date picked in `Textview`.But I keep on getting these error.Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.Thank you.

> sendUserActionEvent()mView==null

This is my code:

```
private DatePickerDialog PickDateDialog;

//I called setDataField() in onCreate  

private void setDateField() {
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    PickDateDialog = new PickDateDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() 
    {

       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    add_show.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
         },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

     }

   //Under  onOptionsItemSelected menu 
   if (id == R.id.action_pickdate) { 

                PickDateDialog.show();
                return true;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works!

Just using his DateFormat

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DatePickerDialog PickDateDialog;
    private TextView add_show;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        add_show = new TextView(this);

        setContentView(add_show);

        setDateField();

    }

    private void setDateField() {
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        PickDateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()  {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    add_show.setText(newDate.getTime().toLocaleString());
                }
            },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("pickdate").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem p1) {

                PickDateDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        }).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.It shows the calendar but the date picked is not shown in the textview.

Comment: What happens when you press "OK"?

Comment: Nothing happens.The date selected is not shown in the TextView.Logcat shows sendUserActionEvent() mView=null

Comment: Can u write the code you use to setText? And what if you print as Toast.makeText()?